# What variable type should I use to store an Arduino pin state?

Tags: c++, arduino

The Arduino docs define the constants `HIGH` and `LOW` for digital I/O pins but don't specify what they are under the hood. So if I want to store a pin state in a variable, what type should the variable be? The logical assumption would be `1` and `0` in an `int` variable, or perhaps `true` and `false` in a `bool`, but I can't find this stated anywhere.

Comment: If you are using C++, use a `bool` instead. If you are using C, go for an `int`.

Comment: What version of `C++` is it? Can you do `decltype(HIGH) mystate;`?

Comment: Thanks, but why the different types for C and C++?

Comment: @Galik I am more than sure that those are macro definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to look at it is that the Arduino folks invented the `HIGH` and `LOW` enumerators (macros?) to hide the fact that maybe, however unlikely, there will be a processor that doesn't use 1 for `HIGH` and 0 for `LOW`.  If you want to write portable, future-proof code, then you should probably stick to `HIGH` and `LOW`.

Another way to look at it is that you (probably) don't really care what the actual pin state is; you care what it means:  the button is pressed, the motion sensor detected someone, the control rods have been lowered, etc.  You can store the meaning in whatever form makes sense to you, like a `bool`, and convert between your conceptual type and the pin state wherever you cross the border:

```
bool button_pressed = digitalRead(button_pin) == LOW;
...
digitalWrite(led_pin, button_pressed ? HIGH : LOW);
```

Don't get overly concerned about the extra code here, as the compiler is going to optimize it away if everything has the "obvious" values and types.

Then again, this is an embedded system where generality is often a secondary concern to size and speed. 
 With an embedded system, you usually know exactly what hardware you're writing for.  If you needed to eek every bit of performance out of this, then you'd probably have to give up using the nice `digitalRead`/`digitalWrite` APIs and work directly with the processor's registers.  And that's OK, too.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation of [`digitalRead()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/digital-io/digitalread/) (Which returns `HIGH` or `LOW`), the value is stored in an `int`, so using `int` seems like a safe bet.

The function [`digitalWrite()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/digital-io/digitalwrite/) takes a pin status (`HIGH` or `LOW`) as a parameter, and searching through [the GitHub repositories from Arduino](https://github.com/search?q=org%3Aarduino+%22void+digitalWrite%22&type=Code) for the definition of that function, there are three different definitions:

```
void digitalWrite(uint32_t, uint32_t);
void digitalWrite(uint8_t, uint8_t);
void digitalWrite(pin_size_t, PinStatus);
```

Where `PinStatus` is an enum:

```
typedef enum {
  LOW     = 0,
  HIGH    = 1,
  CHANGE  = 2,
  FALLING = 3,
  RISING  = 4,
} PinStatus;
```

But `HIGH` and `LOW` are always defined as `1` and `0`, which can definitely be stored in an int (And can be converted to those three types)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can use integers as storage to drive digitalWrite instead of HIGH and LOW as per this post: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=111711.0

-I have not tested this, so please verify before accepting.